# Setting up version control for app already on shared hosting

Tags: python, flask, versioning, dreamhost

Searching for guided info in regards to version control with an already in progress app on a shared host. I am a beginner coder in the python world and have never used a version workflow or structure. I'm trying to get myself organized.

-Python 2.7.8
-Flask framework
-Dreamhost shared hosting
-system running under virtualenv on the host

Should I even bother with version control as a low skill coder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are just starting to learn I probably would not bother with version control. If you are interested however I would take a look at Git:

http://git-scm.com/book

or Mercurial;

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/

It would probably be much better spending your time getting to know the internals of Flask and using python more rather than concentrating on the version control. If you do you use version control at least you could role back if you brake your app.

I would also suggest that this question is very hard to answer. As you go on it may be worth asking a question about something specific :D

Comment: After reading my questing this morning I realize that it would have been better suited in a forum discussion rather than here. I am fairly new to stackoverflow as an actual user and just getting my feet wet. Thank you for the links and information regarding version control, as I'll take that suggestion and focus more on the apps development that versions for now.